# How to prevent release DHCP IP on reboot?

Tags: dhcp

Ubuntu sends dhcp realease on reboot.This kills the lease, changes ip and my DHCP server automaticaly kills DNS record. I want to disable this releasing every time.
Is it possible?
Ubuntu 16.04
isc-dhclient-4.3.3

Comment: What is current value of DHCP lease time? Do you have any output for `grep -i "lease time" /var/log/syslog`? What is the output of `grep lease-time /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1145858/edit) and add corresponding outputs to it.

Comment: Also add `grep -i "renewal in" /var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

This would break whole DHCP purpose. What you are asking for is a static IP. Easiest is to set fixed DHCP record for your MAC on DHCP server.

Comment: This does not break Windows infrastructure and previous versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the purpose of DHCP? To assign an IP. Client should not care what IP it gets normally. If there is a requirement for the same IP then person responsible for assigning IPs (DHCP administrator) needs to be aware and take action. Either assign fixed DHCP IP or take your IP out of the pool and you use static IP.